# Choose specific stats within a list

Tags: python, text, statistics, extract

I really am a newbie in programming and I want to extract only 3 of the lines I get from running this code for this api. This is from nhl.com :

```
import requests
import lxml.html
from pprint import pprint
from sys import exit
import json
import csv

url = "https://api.nhle.com/stats/rest/team?isAggregate=false&reportType=basic&isGame=false&reportName=penaltykill" \
      "&sort=[{%22property%22:%22homePkPctg%22," \
      "%22direction%22:%22DESC%22}]&cayenneExp=leagueId=133%20and%20gameTypeId=2%20and%20seasonId%3E=20192020%20and" \
      "%20seasonId%3C=20192020 "

resp = requests.get(url).text
resp = json.loads(resp)

pprint(resp['data'])
```

I get the following results for all 31 teams (I'm just showing here with the Montréal Canadiens) :

> {'gamesPlayed': 23,
>     'homeGamesPlayed': 12,
>     'homePkPctg': 0.7352,
>     'homePpGoalsAgainst': 9,
>     'homeShNumTimes': 34,
>     'losses': 7,
>     'otLosses': 5,
>     'pkPctg': 0.7361,
>     'points': 27,
>     'ppGoalsAgainst': 19,
>     'roadGamesPlayed': 11,
>     'roadPkPctg': 0.7368,
>     'roadPpGoalsAgainst': 10,
>     'roadShNumTimes': 38,
>     'seasonId': 20192020,
>     'shGoalsFor': 1,
>     'shNumTimes': 72,
>     'teamAbbrev': 'MTL',
>     'teamFullName': 'MontrÃ©al Canadiens',
>     'teamId': 8,
>     'ties': 0,
>     'wins': 11},

Basically I only need the 'homePkPctg' / 'roadPkPctg' / 'teamAbbrev' lines.

I really feel this in an easy one for most people here, but I've been blocked here for a couple of hours. So here I am.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you get when you load a json is a list of dictionaries. So, for every item in your list, you could do something like:

```
# lets say we call it team_data
team_data = resp['data']

# "entry" here is assumed to be a dictionary like the one you show
# for the Montréal Canadiens
for entry in team_data:
    print(entry['homePkPctg'])
    print(entry['roadPkPctg'])
    print(entry['teamAbbrev'])
```

your "lines" are dictionary keys and are accessed as shown above. Might not be exactly true for your case, always depends on the json file/data.

If you run a fetch for every team separately, you can do

```
team_data['homePkPctg']
team_data['roadPkPctg']
team_data['teamAbbrev']
```

instead.

Comment: So if I got you correctly, I should replace  pprint(resp['data']) by                           team_data = resp['data']                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                   for entry in team_data:
    print(entry['homePkPctg'])
    print(entry['roadPkPctg'])
    print(entry['teamAbbrev']) or I just slide it in before pprint(resp['data'])?

Comment: do you need/want to print the values? you could also do ```resp['data']['teamAbbrev']``` (for example) to access the value for the dictionary key "teamAbbrev". I am guessing that you do not need the for loop.

Comment: In the end, I just need those 3 keys to be send in an Excel Sheet. But for the moment, I would like to print the results in the Pycharm console to see what I get before sending it to my Excel document. I'm at a point where I need to see what it generates to understand it better.

Comment: and does my approach help you in any way? You will have to try until you get it right, I think.

Comment: it did! eveything seems to be working fine... thanx a lot.... it is still a work in progress, so chances are pretty good I'll need advices again....